# AudioKit shouldOptimizeForRealtimePlot causing plot to go blank

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I've got an iOS project set up in Xcode utilizing AudioKit to display a realtime plot of a chosen onboard microphone on the iOS device.

I am currently attempting to set the flag for an AKNodeOutputPlot where `shouldOptimizeForRealtimePlot = true`, but I've found that if I even add that line of code, whether it's set to true or false, to the project (in the ViewController the plot in which the plot is displayed, OR as a key-value in IB), the plot no longer displays.

If I remove the line of code, my plot resumes functionality as normal.

Has anyone else run into this?

My plot is setup mostly in IB, I pretty much just use the VC to set the input node and pause/resume the plot, but if you'd like to see any extra code, or a screenshot of my setup in IB, I'm happy to oblige.

Thank you for your assistance.